# NLog AzureAppendBlob not logging

Tags: c#, nlog

I downloaded this [NLog Blob store extension](https://github.com/heemskerkerik/NLog.AzureAppendBlob). When I try to run the test project I am getting this error.

> 2016-03-17 17:23:34.9228 Info Loading assembly name: NLog.AzureBlobStorage
>   2016-03-17 17:23:34.9860 Error Error loading extensions: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'NLog.AzureBlobStorage' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   File name: 'NLog.AzureBlobStorage'

What is the issue? Is this a known bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compile the solution and look at the bin/debug (or release) folder there is **no** "NLog.AzureBlobStorage" dll. But the dll you find is "NLog.AzureAppendBlob". May be it's a issue with the documentation. Use "NLog.AzureAppendBlob" name for the extention,

```
<extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.AzureAppendBlob" />
</extensions>
```

I did a solution search for "NLog.AzureAppendBlob" and renamed 2 other places to get the sample app up and running. Also if you don't have c# 6, you will have to comment some exception handling in "AzureAppendBlobTarget".